# Casimir effect in the double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, casimir-effect

Has anyone to your knowledge, ever detected, or perhaps just tried to detect, a Casimir effect between the plate (with the slits) and the screen behind in the double slit experiment?

Comment: What do you think such an experiment might see?

Comment: The distances involved between the slits and detection screen (if you want to observe any interference fringes) likely preclude casimir effects being observable.

Comment: furthermore the detection screen is not metalic.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect